# Stink bug identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This is a stink bug that I found in Indiranagar, Bangalore. It was dead at that time and had become stiff, so the following are the best pictures I could get. It is 2cms in length. I tried searching on the net on various websites but I didn't find a match for the colouration on the dorsal side. Also, I would like to know what those protrusions on the top half of the shield ( excuse me if 'shield' is the wrong terminology) are. They seemed to be quite a troublesome feature as none of the reference pictures I saw on the net seemed to have bugs with these 'protrusions' .

[image]

[image]

Comment: First that comes to mind are *Euschistus sp.*, which are known for these kinds of protruding shoulders, but I'm not sure if they're in India or not.. also considering *Halyomorpha sp.*.

Comment: I agree, but none of the species (which I found on the net) of Euschistus sp. Have such pronounced protrusions. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: No, I don't believe you are.. to me, it is confusing because the shoulders on the OP are saw toothed, which would indicate a common brown stink bug, as apposed to marmorated brown stink bug, but the antenna would indicate marmorated. The same can be said about the black/white checker pattern. Hmm..

Comment: I looked through the appropriate volume of _Fauna of British India_ but couldn't find a good match (not surprising; the volume in question dates from 1902 and illustrates 201 of the 542 species known at the time); at the time _Euschistus_ had not yet been found in India, and the species of _Halyomorpha_ illustrated is not a good match.

Comment: I've been searching for quite some time in different subfamilies of Pentatomidae and have to admit defeat. Until now I'm unable to retrieve any information about the marvelous bug you have found.
The pictures you took are really great, by the way!

Maybe you can ask Dr. Salini for help? :)
She studied 94 species of Pentatomidae according to the following website: http://www.nbair.res.in/salini.php